# Is there any way to simulate datas with a trend with the package sarima in R?

Tags: r, simulation

I could not find out, whether there is a way to simulate datas with a trend and/or season with the package `sarima` in R. It should be a seasonal ARIMA model, so that´s why I am using the sarima package.

I have already tried to simulate a seasonal ARIMA model with the package `sarima` and it worked, but I  also need a trend in my simulated datas to see, if the Algorithm of `Ets`-Function  identifies the trend and/or the season of my simulated datas.

```
library("sarima")
q=sim_sarima(n =144, model = list(sma=0.4, ma=0.4,sar=0.5,ar=0.5,nseasons=12,simga2 =1)
q = ts(q, start = 1, end= 12, frequency = 12)
w = exp(q)
ts.plot(w)
e = ets(w)
e$method
```

Comment: Perhaps possible https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/astsa/versions/1.9/topics/sarima

Comment: Have a look at https://rpubs.com/SunnyBingoMe/sarima

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO or Google, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use argument `xintercept` to add arbitrary trend to the ARIMA equation. 
Extending your example:

```
sim_sarima(n = 144, model = list(sma = 0.4, ma = 0.4, sar = 0.5,ar = 0.5, 
    nseasons = 12, sigma2 = 1), xintercept = 1:144)
```

Notice that this kind of trend is added as a regression term on the right-hand side of the ARIMA equation.

Admittedly, the documentation is patchy. Please feel free to raise issue(s) at
https://github.com/GeoBosh/sarima/issues. If possible, they will be dealt with in the forthcoming release of the package.